# How to calculate sum of count of array elements of multiple arrays by order and limit?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, dictionary, set

I have 3 arrays of 3 different types. Each array contains the count of an id (which might be duplicate like `arrayOfB`).

Each id has a limit value of count property is 10 (the count includes different types. Ex: if unique1 has 10 counts in type A, when process type B for unique1, it will be not processed).

```
const arrayOfA = [
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 10, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 20, "id": "UID2"
    },
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 1, "id": "UID4"
    },
];

const arrayOfB = [
    {
        "type": "B", "count": 5, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "B", "count": 5, "id": "UID3"
    },
];

const arrayOfC = [
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 6, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 6, "id": "UID4"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 3, "id": "UID2"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 3, "id": "UID3"
    },
]
```

The output will be like:

```
Map {
  'UID1|A' => 10,
  'UID2|A' => 10,
  'UID4|A' => 1,
  'UID3|B' => 5,
  'UID4|C' => 6 }
```

I used a set to hold id, which already has the maximum count and map to hold the output.

```
const maxed = new Set();
const elements = new Map();

arrayOfA.forEach(element => {
    if (element.count > 10) {
        maxed.add(`${element.id}`);
        elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, 10);
        console.log(elements)
        return;
    }

    if (elements.has(`${element.id}|${element.type}`)) {
        const newCount = elements.get(`${element.id}|${element.type}`) + element.count;
        newCount > 10 ? elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, 10) : elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, newCount);
        console.log(elements)
        return;
    }

    elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, element.count);
});

arrayOfB.forEach(element => {
    if (maxed.has(`${element.id}`)) {
        console.log(elements)
        return;
    }

    const countOfA = elements.has(`${element.id}|A`) ? elements.get(`${element.id}|A`) : 0;
    let newCount = countOfA + element.count;

    if (elements.has(`${element.id}|${element.type}`)) {
        newCount = newCount + element.get(`${element.id}|${element.type}`);
    }

    if (newCount > 10) {
        maxed.add(`${element.id}`);
        if ((10 - countOfA) > 0) elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, 10 - countOfA);
        console.log(elements)
        return;
    }

    elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, element.count);
})

arrayOfC.forEach(element => {
    if (maxed.has(`${element.id}`)) {
        console.log(elements)
        return;
    }

    const countOfA = elements.has(`${element.id}|A`) ? elements.get(`${element.id}|A`) : 0
    const countOfB = elements.has(`${element.id}|C`) ? elements.get(`${element.id}|C`) : 0

    let newCount = countOfA + countOfB + element.count;

    if (elements.has(`${element.id}|${element.type}`)) {
        newCount = newCount + element.get(`${element.id}|${element.type}`);
    }

    if (newCount > 10) {
        maxed.add(`${element.id}`);
        if ((10 - countOfA - countOfB) > 0); elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, 10 - countOfA - countOfB);
        console.log(elements)
        return;
    }

    elements.set(`${element.id}|${element.type}`, element.count);
})
```

I want to ask about another faster implementation if any. I estimated my big O will be O(n) (n is the total length of 3 arrays). If elements of arrays do not contain the same id.

Edit:
Big thanks to you all, but seems like there's one edge case. The answers couldn't handle

```
var arrayOfA = [
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 10, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 20, "id": "UID2"
    },
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 1, "id": "UID4"
    },
];

const arrayOfB = [
    {
        "type": "B", "count": 5, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "B", "count": 5, "id": "UID3"
    },
    {
        "type": "B", "count": 1, "id": "UID3"
    },
];

var arrayOfC = [
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 6, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 6, "id": "UID4"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 3, "id": "UID2"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 3, "id": "UID3"
    },
]
```

In arrayOfB, I have the UID3 occurs twice, so your answers doesn't seem to work on that case.

Comment: Rather than using string manipulation, you could use Maps of Maps. (Or, more simply, just objects of objects.)

Comment: I don't understand your 'limit' functionality. Can you explain it again please?

Comment: So, let say a unique id UID1 already has 10 counts of type A. When we go to the array of type B, the same unique id UID1 has X counts of type B. This amount of counts will be not included because unique id UID1 already reached the limit.

Comment: @trmaphi okay, thanks, I think I understand now

Comment: btw, you had an empty statement here: `if ((10 - ACount - certCount) > 0); elements`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `Set` for a `maxed` `id`, you could sum the `count` for every `id` and use it for all following arrays.

```js
const
    getKey = (...a) => a.join('|'),
    rawData = [{ type: "A", count: 10, id: "UID1" }, { type: "A", count: 20, id: "UID2" }, { type: "A", count: 1, id: "UID4" }],
    rawData3 = [{ type: "B", count: 5, id: "UID1" }, { type: "B", count: 5, id: "UID3" }],
    rawData2 = [{ type: "C", count: 6, id: "UID1" }, { type: "C", count: 6, id: "UID4" }, { type: "C", count: 3, id: "UID2" }, { type: "C", count: 3, id: "UID3" }],
    elements = new Map,
    sums = new Map;

[rawData, rawData3, rawData2].forEach(a => a.forEach(({ type, count, id }) => {
    var sum = sums.get(id) || 0,
        key = getKey(id, type);

    sums.set(id, sum + count);

    if (sum >= 10) return;
    if (sum + count > 10) {
        if (10 - sum > 0) elements.set(key, 10 - sum);
        return;
    }
    elements.set(key, count);
}));

[...elements].map(a => console.log(a.join(': ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this gives the expected outcome?

Comment: i am not sure either. but `B` is missing in the op's result set.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that you have missed to include "B" in your expected results set, two nested loops can provide the manipulation and filtering you want.

```js
function getIdSummary(arrays) {

    const maxValue = 10;

    //Array of objects which we later conver to a map
    //The aim is ease of indexing during the iterations
    var summary = []


    //A heler to find if a maxed uid is found in the summary
    function isMaxed(uid) {
        return summary.some(item => {
            return item.uid === uid && item.count >= maxValue;
        })
    }



    //Iterate all the arrays
    arrays.forEach(anInputArray => {

        //Iterate each array
        anInputArray.forEach(item => {
            if (!isMaxed(item.id)) {
                summary.push({uid: item.id, type: item.type, count: item.count > maxValue ? 10 : item.count})
            }

        })

    })

    return new Map(summary.map(obj => {
        return [obj.uid + '|' + obj.type, obj.count]
    }))


}



var arrayOfA = [
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 10, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 20, "id": "UID2"
    },
    {
        "type": "A", "count": 1, "id": "UID4"
    },
];

const arrayOfB = [
    {
        "type": "B", "count": 5, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "B", "count": 5, "id": "UID3"
    },
];

var arrayOfC = [
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 6, "id": "UID1"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 6, "id": "UID4"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 3, "id": "UID2"
    },
    {
        "type": "C", "count": 3, "id": "UID3"
    },
]


var m = getIdSummary([arrayOfA, arrayOfB, arrayOfC]);

console.log(Array.from(m));
```